# Liferay: how can i upload a image from portlet preferences?

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, liferay-6, portlet

Using liferay 6.2, I'm currently trying to create a portlet where a image is displayed.

I have already done this but I need to be able to change the image from the preferences uploading a new one. I already have a form to upload a file but I'm not able to upload the file and show it on the portlet.

This is the form in the edit.jsp

```
<aui:form action="<%=editPreferencesURL%>" method="post">
<aui:input label="image" name="Image" type="file"/>
<aui:button type="submit" />
</aui:form>
```

This is the renderURL:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="editPreferencesURL">
   <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/folder/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

Comment: Please include your declaration of editPreferencesURL. In assuming this is an actionURL?

Comment: Added, its a renderURL

Answer (score 1):

The `editPreferencesURL` that you mention is a `renderURL` - for posting a form you'll need an `actionURL`.

A renderURL is typically used to show the raw form (e.g. it's fine to use it to link to the edit mode form) but not for updating data. During *render* a portlet cannot change state, during *action* it can.

Comment: i have changed the  <portlet:renderURL for  <portlet:actionURL, i guess now i have to create a function on the MCVPortlet with the same name that actionURL have but still i don't know how to actually upload de image

Comment: well, yes, you'll have to implement an action handler. There should be plenty of samples for uploads within a portlet - just reuse the code that you find there. Then decide where to put the image and how to reference it.